# How to find a value from a table and prepend it to a div

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, append, prepend

I want to find a value that has been entered in a text field from a table, and then prepend a name that is on the row of that code.

```
$('#InputCode').blur(function(){
$('#Table tr').find(this).val()
('.NameCell').append('#NameResult')
})
```

Here the edit:

```
<table id="Table1" width="306" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Zip</th>
    <th scope="col" class="Names">Names</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0871</td>
    <td>Dan</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0877</td>
    <td>Dan</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0771</td>
    <td>Bonn</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0772</td>
    <td>Conblentz</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input name="" type="text" id="InputCode">
<div id="NameResult">
</div>
```

When a user enter a code into an input field, a name matching the code must be appended/prepended into a div, taken from a table

Comment: `$('#Table tr').find(this).val()` isn't it equivalent to `this.value` ???

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're after, but your code isn't quite right. What is the source for the value? #InputCode or the tr? What is #NameResult?

Comment: When a users enter a code into an input field, a name matching the code must be appended/prepended into a div.

Answer (score 0):

try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/4bz3t/)

**JS Code**

```
$('#InputCode').blur(function () {
    var input = $(this).val();
    $t = $('td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == input
    });
    var res = $t.next().text();
    $('#NameResult').append(res)
})
```